# What are the criteria Windows 10 uses to place the page file?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, pagefile

I've recently noticed that my own workstation has felt a bit sluggish but thought nothing of it at first. It has two really fast 500GB NVMe SSDs and one 1TB HDD.

Then I played a game - not something I do that regularly - and I had micro freezes like every 5 seconds. I also noticed that it coincided with a click from the HDD. I ran a few diagnostics routines - nothing seems wrong. But then I see a 32GB pagefile in the root folder - with todays date on it... It shouldn't be there!

Turns out that in the default "Windows will take care of business"-setting, it disables page files on the SSDs and only uses the HDD! Is this behaviour to be expected?

Comment: If you don't have a page file on the SSD then you must have done that yourself.  You can allow the system to manage the page file.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, but I'm pretty sure I didn't do that myself. Pagefile settings were on auto when I started looking it up so it definitely Windows itself that did this.

Comment: Windows has no problem creating a page file on a SSD.  If your system drive doesn’t currently have one, change your configuration, so your system manages the size of the page file